# Reprojecting in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to reproject base layers in OpenLayers?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13249/how-to-reproject-base-layers-in-openlayers)

I Am trying to reproject my map from epsg:4326 to epsg:900913 but I couldn't do it. here is my codes

OpenLayers Example

```
<div id="panel" class="olControlEditingToolbar"><div class="olControlNavigationItemActive olButton"></div><div class="olControlDrawFeaturePointItemInactive olButton"></div><div class="olControlDrawFeaturePathItemInactive olButton"></div><div class="olControlDrawFeaturePolygonItemInactive olButton"></div></div>


  <style>
@media screen
{
    #map{width:975px; height:750px; border: 2px solid black;}
}
</style>

  <script defer="defer" type="text/javascript">


    var lon = -84.722147;
    var lat = 49.298594;    
    var zoom = 6;


    var map, layer;


    mainURL = "http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=/wwwroot/Practice/Practice.map",  
    map = new OpenLayers.Map({
        div: "map"

    });

  Geologist_2011 = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("Geologist_2011",
        mainURL,
        {'layers': 'Geologist_2011', transparent: true, format: 'image/gif'},
        {isBaseLayer: true}
    );


    map.addLayers([Geologist_2011]);




    map.zoomToMaxExtent();  
    map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon, lat), zoom);


    map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());
    map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition());
    map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.OverviewMap());
    map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.ScaleLine({maxWidth: 300}));

    var panel = new OpenLayers.Control.NavToolbar({'div':OpenLayers.Util.getElement('paneldiv')});
        map.addControl(panel);



    vlayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector( "Editable" );
        map.addLayer(vlayer);
        var container = document.getElementById("panel");
        var panel = new OpenLayers.Control.EditingToolbar(
            vlayer, {div: container}
        );
        map.addControl(panel);




  </script>
```