# Using Google Maps as base layer with overlays (vector & rasters) in OpenLayers

Tags: coordinate-system, openlayers-2

Currently i'm using OpenLayers 2.12 and geoserver 2.2.4.

On initial load the application has the base layer(say baseLayer_1) of 4326 projection with overlay layers of One WMS layer(say worldWms) and one WFS(say gridWFS) layer with same projection(EPSG:4326).

when I try to change the google map(say googlebaselayer_2) as my  base layer via toggle function the overlay layers  worldWms,gridWFS couldn't overlay successfully.
Only empty boxes loaded.

```
        '//map object declaration
        map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', {

                minResolution: "auto",
                maxResolution: "auto",
                maxExtent: [-180, -90, 180, 90],

                //maxResolution: 0.3515625,
                projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
                numZoomLevels: 6,
                //resolutions: [0.3515625, 0.17578125, 0.087890652, 0.0439453125, 0.02197265625, 0.010986328125],
                controls: [
                    new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(),
                   new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar(),
                new OpenLayers.Control.Graticule({
                numPoints: 1, 
                labelled: true
                })
                ]
        });

        //Base Layer 1
        baseLayer_1 = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
            "baseLayer_1",
            geoserverUrl + "wms",
            {
                layers: "InitialBaseLayerName"

            },
            {
                isBaseLayer: true
            }
        );

        //Google base Layer

        googlebaselayer_2 =  new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
                "Google Physical",
                {
                    wrapDateLine: false,
                    sphericalMercator: true,
                    minZoomLevel: 3,
                    maxZoomLevel: 8

                }
            );

        $('#toggleMap').click(function(){
            var toggleElement = $(this);
                //alert("value-->"+toggleElement.val());
            if(toggleElement.val() == 'google'){

                map.setBaseLayer(googlebaselayer_2);

            }else {

                map.setBaseLayer(baseLayer_1);

            }
        });

        //WMS layer addition

         worldWms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
            "worldWms", 
            geoserverUrl + "wms",
            {
                layers: "wmsLayerName",
                type: "png",
                transparent: "true",
                styles: "countries_boundary"
            },
            {
                isBaseLayer: false
            }
        );
        map.addLayers([worldWms]);

    // vectorlayer adddition

    gridWFS = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("gridWFS", {
            strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX()],
            protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
                url:geoserverUrl+"wfs",
                version: "1.1.0",
                featureNS:"http://www.extract.com",
                featureType:"gridLayerName",
                srsName: "EPSG:4326",
                 geometryName:"the_geom",
                outputFormat: 'json', 
                readFormat: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON()
            }),
                styleMap: style_solar

        });
        map.addLayers([gridWFS]);'
```

how to toggle between both baseLayer_1 and googlebaselayer_2 with overlay layers.

Can you suggest a possible solution to overcome this problem?

I have referred to [Using base layer of two different projections (Spherical Mercator and WGS84) in OpenLayers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24572) but i am not able to get it in detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google maps is not a WMS service, and the terms of use of Google Maps itself prevent legal usage of it in a server side application, unless of course you have some sort of commercial contract with Google that entitles you to use their tiles outside of a browser.

Comment: I'm surprised to see this as an accepted answer, as it in no way answers the question. It's a long time since I've used OpenLayers (possibly since this question was new!)  but I think the issue is that you can't do `map.setBaseLayer()` on an `OpenLayers.Layer.Google()` layer (because, as you say, it isn't a WMS), but it's entirely possible to add the Google layer anyway (just as the OP is adding a WMS non-base layer) _[and the TOS reference is irrelevant to the question -- it's not being used in a server-side application, anyway. OpenLayers is client-side]_