# How to reproject base layers in QGIS once OpenLayers layers are removed?

Tags: qgis, qgis-openlayers-plugin

I recently discovered the wonders of the OpenStreetMap maps, however now all my projects have all gone curved.

Is there a way to go back to how they were set originally.

Opposite to this question:

[How to reproject base layers in OpenLayers?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13249/how-to-reproject-base-layers-in-openlayers)

So basically how to reproject base layers once OpenLayers layers are removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if I understand you correctly. You have made your own projects in some projection. After adding OSM via openlayers plugin your **project** CRS has automatically changed to EPSG:3857. If you remove the openlayers layer, you can switch back to any other CRS.

If your data is in a projected CRS, you can rightclick on the layer `-> Layer-CRS for project`

If your data is lat/lon degrees, you might better choose a projected CRS, e.g. the UTM CRS for your part of the world.

There is no need to reproject the data, QGIS can **display** it in any CRS you want.

Comment: Cheers. Panic over i think.